# Is this proof in which I prove a statement by the contrapositive correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

For all positive integers $x$, if $x^2-4x+1$ is even, then $x$ is odd.

What I did:

Proof:

We prove the contrapositive: if $x$ is even, then $x^2-4x+1$ is odd.

1) Assume that $x$ is even and positive, then $x=2k$ such that $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k \neq 0$

2) Then, $(2k)^2-4(2k)+1=4k^2-8k+1$

3) So, let $u$ = $2k^2-4k$

4) Then, $4k^2-8k+1$ is equivalent to $2u+1$

5) Since $2$ times any integer is even, $2u$ is even.

6) Since an even number plus an odd number is odd, $2u+1$ is odd (Because $2u$ is even and $1$ is odd.)

7) Therefore, $x^2-4x+1$ is odd.

Is this a correct and complete proof? Please feel free to give constructive criticism. I want to improve my proof writing skills.

Comment: looks very good!

Comment: This is most certainly correct :). Well done :)

Comment: As the other comments say, this is correct. But since you ask for criticism on writing, I'll nitpick just a little. The phrase 'is equivalent to' is not what you mean here. You mean equals, so use '='. Using 'is equivalent to' only adds a weird ambiguity. It's generally good to favor unambiguous notation. Again, this is super minor and wouldn't even deserve a -0.5.

Comment: It sure is. One little flaw, a typo: in 2), You mean "Then, $(2k)^2 - ... = 4k^2 - ...$" rather than "Then, $(2k^2) -$ ...".

Comment: @BrianO Thank you, I fixed it.

Comment: Also, you do need the assumption that x is positive. Your argument works fine for zero and negative x.

Comment: I did assume that x is positive in step 1)

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct; I have two advices to give you.

1) You do not need to be so detailed, just a couple of lines are enough. For example:

Assume $x$ is even, $ x= 2k$; then

$$ x^2 - 4x + 1 = (2k)^2 - 4(2k) + 1 = 4k^2 - 8k +1 =  2 (2k^2 - 4k) + 1, $$

and this is odd because it is of the form $ 2u + 1. $

2) Try to find out direct proofs whenever it is possible, and especially if the statement is relatively easy. A direct proof could be:

Assume $x^2 - 4x + 1$ is even, $ x^2 - 4x + 1 = 2n. $ Then
$$ x^2 = 2n + 4x -1 = 2 (n+2x) - 1 $$
and this is odd, which implies $x$ odd.

Comment: You are missing the final step: $x^2$ odd implies $x$ odd. (Yes, it's obvious, but hardly more obvious than the initial proposition. So it should at least be explicitly stated, and perhaps even proven.)

Comment: Yes of course, I assumed it is obvious or already proven.